# Can I use the thumbnails of external links in a news aggregator website?

Tags: googlebot, links, pagerank, copyright, thumbnail

I'm building a site where I need to post some news (links) about a specific subject.

I'll gather them around and aggregate them on my site.

The question is:

Can I use their thumbnail to promote their own links?

**For example:** (from `example.com`):

[image]

Of course this will be pointed to the specific `example.com` link URL for that post and the **Source: example.com** will also be displayed.

I'll be getting news from many sites, not just `example.com`.

Is this legal? Also, how will Googlebot react to this, when it comes to pageranking?

Comment: Just found out that `http://popurls.com/` does exactly that. So I guess it's not illegal.

Comment: Here are a few answers that may help you to understand copyright. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86631/can-you-be-sued-for-using-publicly-used-images-on-a-blog-without-copyright-permi/86637#86637 https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/am-i-legally-allowed-to-cache-other-peoples-web-pages-on-my-site/103279#103279 https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-illegal-is-it-to-get-data-from-a-100-accessible-but-not-exposed-api/73913#73913

Comment: In short, No. You cannot use another's image without it being transformative.

Comment: @closetnoc Those images are often (if not 100% of the time) provided via RSS feeds. Does it make a difference whether you're accessing through the RSS feed or copying the `src` yourself? (asking this in the context of **newspaper** websites)

Comment: RSS feeds, by themselves, do not grant permission, however, there may be permission granted somewhere such as in the AUP (acceptable use policy), license for use, or other mechanism. I would assume that in an RSS feed, depending upon the intent of the feed, that permission could be assumed. For example, is the feed intended for other sites to use to create snippets and links to the originator site? I do not work in this realm, so I may not be of much use. Sorry. I will let others answer. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc thank you for your help!